# Random unique Friday dates within a year with Excel

Tags: excel, random, unique, excel-formula

i need to generate unique random Friday dates within a specific year.

i have a more or less working example of: Random unique dates, Mon to Fri, within a year
where you can check at: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/11/26/create-random-dates-mon-to-fri-within-a-year-in-excel/
the problem of this examle: it`s not friday dates, and its not generating uniques dates, there are duplicates ones.

The list must generate N random dates the N number is informed in a specific Cell. example:
A1: 4 ( then the list must generate 4 random dates)
A1: 8 ( then the list must generate 8 random dates)
A1: 20 ( then the list must generate 20 random dates)

If i have the option i would ask to do not use vba.. is there a way doing just in excel-formula?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's one way to do that - this will give you a random number of Fridays in the specified year...to simplify it only picks from the first 52 Fridays, if there are 53 Fridays in the year it won't pick that 53rd one....although formula could be altered to do so.

In A1 put the year, e.g. 2013, in A2 put the number to generate, e.g. 4 and in C1 put some text like "Dates" - now in C2 copy this formula:

`=IF(ROWS(C$2:C2)>A$2,"",SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,DATE(A$1,1,1+7*ROW(INDIRECT("1:52")))-WEEKDAY(DATE(A$1,1,2)))=0,DATE(A$1,1,1+7*ROW(INDIRECT("1:52")))-WEEKDAY(DATE(A$1,1,2))),RANDBETWEEN(1,53-ROWS(C$2:C2))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+ and copy down to C53. Latter cells will stay blank if the A2 number is low. Now you can just change A1 and A2 as required to generate new lists

Here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/38xryyec14eli3k/RandomFridays.xlsx) to an example - A2 is a random number - press F9 to re-generate
"Test" column just shows you how many instances there are of each date - as there should be no repeats that should always be one

...or here's [another version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgzxsevlpv8tsat/RandomDays.xlsx) with some helper cells to simplify the formula - specify year in B1, number of dates to show in B2 and day in B3:

Formula in C2 is

=IF(ROWS(D$2:D2)>B$2,"",SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,B$4+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B$5))*7-7)=0,B$4+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B$5))*7-7),RANDBETWEEN(1,B$5+1-ROWS(D$2:D2))))

Comment: Hello Barry! thank you a lot! great code! may I also ask one more question? i have made a modification to your file, you can check at: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yd082vnqyi9kpt0/RandomFridays%20rev1.xlsx) the goal is to generate dates that does not belong to the other sheets dates range. In the other 2 sheets i have dates ranges (itens with start and end dates) the generated random dates must not be between those dates in that sheets. is that possible? thank you !!!

Comment: Yes, I think you can do that - personally I don't normally like to edit others' answers.....except for perhaps obvious typos....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple equation that you can paste in A1 and drag down.

```
=DATE(2012,1,(RANDBETWEEN(-100,100)*7)-1)
```

Here is how it works.

I start by generating a date beginning in 2012.
`=date(2012,1,1)` happens to be a saturday.  So, I know I need to subtract 1 day from the final date.

Next, I know that a week is 7 days long, so I generated a random number from -100 to 100 `randbetween(-100,100)` and multiple this number by 7.  This is going to give you dates within 4 years of 2012, either direction.

Every date currently is going to be saturday, because it's a multiple of 7 days from it.  So, subtract 1.